# Not able to do database changes properly iteratively in C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server

I maintain a list of operations(Deletion and Updations) to be done in Database. 
I iterate the list using `foreach` and perform those operations. Below is example pseudo code. I am using Entity Framework and SQL Server as database behind it.

```
foreach ( dbChange in dbChanges)
        {
            switch (dbChange.Operation)
            {
                case Add:
                    queryStr = String.Format("DELETE FROM {0} WHERE {1} = {2}",
                        dbChange.TableName,
                        dbChange.PrimaryKeyName,
                        dbChange.PrimaryKeyValue);
                    break;
                case Update:
                    queryStr = String.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} = '{2}' WHERE {3} = {4}",
                        dbChange.TableName,
                        dbChange.ColumnName,
                        dbChange.PreviousValue,
                        dbChange.PrimaryKeyName,
                        dbChange.PrimaryKeyValue);
                    break;
            }

         DBQuery.ExecuteCommand(ConnectionString, queryStr, 10);

        }
```

**My Problem:** It works perfectly fine and does the required changes. But sometimes randomly the DB operation are not done properly. Like some value is not updated or some row is not deleted.

I tried a lot to figure out possible reason behind it. What may be the possible cause (race condition or something ? ) and rectification for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use EF in the proper way instead of using `DbQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding SaveChanges or other queries that changes records values after the query, you need to track exceptions and the result of ExecuteCommand (that should be 1) otherwise it will be hard to understand the problem.

Anyway, just for start the errors could be:
1. SQL Syntax (SQL Injections in update query or invalid field names). So replace `dbChange.PreviousValue` with `dbChange.PreviousValue.Replace("'", "''")` and quote field names.
2. Referential integrity violation (you can check it using the ExecuteCommand return value.